# How to get this.value as an argument in a function placed in an event handler in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function change_myselect(sel) {
  return new sel;
}


 function customers () {

    var  xmlhttp, myObj, i, tbl = '';

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        tbl += '<table border="1">';
        for (i in myObj) {
          tbl += '<tr><td>' + myObj[i] + '</td></tr>' ;
        }
        tbl += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('showSelection').innerHTML = tbl;
      }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'suppliers.txt', true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Make a table based on the value of a drop down menu.</h2>

<select onchange="change_myselect(customers)">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="customers">Customers</option>
  <option value="products">Products</option>
  <option value="suppliers">Suppliers</option>
</select>

<p id="showSelection"></p>
```

In the code above it works because I've written manually CUSTOMERS in the change_myselect function as an argument.

```js
function change_myselect(sel) {
  return  new sel;
}

 function customers () {

    var  xmlhttp, myObj, i, tbl = '';

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        tbl += '<table border="1">';
        for (i in myObj) {
          tbl += '<tr><td>' + myObj[i] + '</td></tr>' ;
        }
        tbl += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('showSelection').innerHTML = tbl;
      }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'customers.txt', true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Make a table based on the value of a drop down menu.</h2>

<select onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="customers">Customers</option>
  <option value="products">Products</option>
  <option value="suppliers">Suppliers</option>
</select>

<p id="showSelection"></p>
```

I want to make a table based on the value of a drop-down menu. I've used an ONCHANGE event handler to get the value of the option and pass it to the change_myselect function to retrieve the respective information from the server with JSON. When i write the name of the CUSTOMERS function, in the change_myselect function it works fine. But when i use THIS.VALUE, it does not work. I've used the NEW key word to return and call the CUSTOMERS function without using parentheses.

Comment: Have you somehow messed up the code when you've pasted it to the post? Currently `change_myselect` does practically nothing.

Comment: When change_myselect gets the value of customers from the "option select"  call the CUSTOMERS function and show the names.

Comment: There's nothing calling `customers` in the provided example. `change_myselect` just returns its return value to the bit space. `sel` in `change_myselect` is just a string, it's the value of the selected option. I guess you've more similar functions to `customers`, and you want to call a function with the same name as the value of the selected option is?

Comment: I created a function by the name of CUSTOMERS. So when the value of option becomes CUSTOMERS, change_myselect calls the CUSTOMERS function and show the result.

Comment: No, `change_myselect` returns a string back to the online handler, where it is never used.

Comment: When i manually write CUSTOMERS in change_myselect, it works. But when i want to use this.value, it does not work.

Comment: Please re-read my second comment, and answer the question in it, maybe we can get this solved.

Comment: Umh ... Actually the code breaks in `change_myselect`, because `sel` is not a function.

Comment: Everything you get from the HTML is string. When you pass literally written `customers` to `change_myselect`, it is a reference to the said function. When you pass `this.value`, it is just a string. That's why you get an error instead. Actually, in the first case, you should not use `return new sel`. Instead you should do `sel();`. But that won't work in the second case. I asked this already, but please confirm, you want to call a function which has the same name as the value of the selected option?

Comment: Yes. I created a function by the name of CUSTOMERS which is the same as the value of the selected option. So when i get CUSTOMERS in the value of option it calls the function CUSTOMERS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you get from the HTML is string. When you pass literally written `customers` to `change_myselect` function, it's a reference to `customers` function. When you pass `this.value`, it's just a string. That's why you get an error instead of a function call.

Based on your code, it looks like you want to call a function which has the same name as the value of the selected option. In JavaScript, strings can't directly be converted to references (in a rational way), which is what you need, when you refer a function. You'd need a helper object to get the reference.

```js
// Helper object contains methods calling the functions
const handlers = {
  customers () {customers();},
  products () {products();},
  suppliers () {suppliers();}
}

function change_myselect(sel) {
  // Check, if the passed property name is a function in handlers object
  if (typeof handlers[sel] === 'function') {
    // A method named as the passed string was found
    // Call the found method
    handlers[sel]();
  }
}

function customers () {
  console.log('customers called');
}
function products () {
  console.log('products called');
}
function suppliers () {
  console.log('suppliers called');
}
```

```html
<h2>Make a table based on the value of a drop down menu.</h2>

<select onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
  <option value="">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="customers">Customers</option>
  <option value="products">Products</option>
  <option value="suppliers">Suppliers</option>
</select>

<p id="showSelection"></p>
```

In `change_myselect`, the code checks, if the helper object contains a method which has the same name as the passed string. For this we use bracket notation, where the string in the brackets is evaluated as a property of the object before the brackets. If the passed property is found, the code calls the method in `handlers` object, using the bracket notation again. Notice the parenthesis at the end of the line. The helper method then calls the actual function, which does the job.

If you've `customer` function to call only, then just leave the methods referring to the other functions out from the helper object. You can also simplify the code by placing the code of the functions to the methods of `handlers` object directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for solving the problem and also a clear explanation. :)
I have two questions about the handlers object.
1) I normally create an object with name/value pairs
like this, `var car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};`
but handlers object is different.

2) I assume the properties in the handlers object are functions.
I normally create functions like this,
`function name(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3) {
  // code to be executed
}`
but functions in the handlers object have no 
the word "function" before the name.

Comment: I am a newbie in coding and JS so my questions may sound very primitive. :)

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, they're functions. It's an ES6 shorthand method name, which you can use in [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and classes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue with code above is that you are referring to

```
this.value
```

You could revisit your `change_myselect` function to expect `event` as argument and then extract selected value from event, for example:

```
var change_myselect = function(event) {
  var selectedValue = event && event.target && event.target.value || '';
  return selectedValue || '';
};
```

make sure that you also modify HTML portion of your code to to pass event as argument as well:

```
<select onchange="change_myselect(event)">
```

Also you could store output of `change_myselect` in another variable to use down the road in your http request logic.

Comment: Yes. You're right. The issue is this.value. I will try this and I think it will work. Thank you. :)

Comment: @EliasAchilles it's hard to tell without exact error, however, it looks like you would like to fetch txt file based on value from your select, in this case you could try code from comment below with `performXhr`, with some modifications:

`performXhr(entity)` – should take event instead ``performXhr(event)`, and add one more var
`var entity = event && event.target && event.target.value || '';`

example: https://jsbin.com/lowuzipiri/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: `this` in an inline event handler does not refer to `window`, it refers to the element where the listener is set.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't use your select's value anywhere or performing any xhr request.
Try changing your js code to something like this:

```
 function performXhr(entity) {
      var xmlhttp,
        myObj,
        i,
        tbl = "";

      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          tbl += '<table border="1">';
          for (i in myObj) {
            tbl += "<tr><td>" + myObj[i] + "</td></tr>";
          }
          tbl += "</table>";
          document.getElementById("showSelection").innerHTML = tbl;
        }
      };

      xmlhttp.open("GET", `${entity}.txt`, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

and your HTML markup

```
    <select onchange="performXhr(this.value)">
      <option value="">Choose an option</option>
      <option value="customers">Customers</option>
      <option value="products">Products</option>
      <option value="suppliers">Suppliers</option>
    </select>
```